# How to apply the second mean value theorem on $ \int_{Y^2}^{{Y'}^2} z^{-1/2} e^{2 \pi i N z} dz $?

Tags: complex-analysis

$Y' > Y > 0$ is given. $N$ is a positive integer. How we can apply the second mean value theorem on $\int_{Y^2}^{{Y'}^2} z^{-1/2} e^{2 \pi i N z} dz $ to conclude that this integral has absolute value $O(Y^{-1})$ as $Y \rightarrow \infty$? I checked the second mean value theorem for integrals and I see that we need a bounded, increasing function as one of the terms in the integrand. I appreciate any help.
Note: I add the Number Theory tag because this question appears in Davenport's Multiplicative Theory Chapter 2, where one tries to evaluate the explicit value of Gauss sum G(1).

Comment: apply it separately to the real and imaginary parts  - note that it holds for decreasing bounded functions too like $1/\sqrt z$ so here for the real part say, we get $\int_{Y^2}^{{Y'}^2} z^{-1/2} \cos 2\pi Nz dz=Y^{-1}\int_{Y^2}^{\zeta} \cos 2\pi Nz dz$ for some $Y^2 \le \zeta \le {Y'}^2$ and since the new integral is clearly at most $1/(\pi N)$ in absolute value the result is clear; integration by parts works easily too